# wx python how to place a button on a frame

Tags: wxpython

I have two buttons on a panel. I want one on the left and one on the right. There must be a simple way but I can't see it (the (400, 0) spacer is just an example; it should work on any panel)

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,
                          'Demonstrate wxPython button')
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Fit()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)

        # Button
        button_sizer = self._button_sizer(frame)

        # Main sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add((400, 0))
        main_sizer.Add(button_sizer)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def _button_sizer(self, frame):
        cmd_save = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_SAVE)
        cmd_cancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button_sizer.Add(cmd_save)
        button_sizer.Add(cmd_cancel, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        return button_sizer


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

(Sorry about this; StackOverflow want more text)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porttitor donec, eget dolor tempor imperdiet, dignissim a sit wisi sed, congue sit accumsan aliquam urna fusce. Placerat vel ligula curabitur in nostra nunc, lorem lorem morbi in aliquet. Etiam ultricies ante sed at aenean id, ligula nibh aenean fusce sapien, ipsum felis sapien eu, mollis ut tempus odio suspendisse fames. A massa wisi sed nunc maecenas pretium, massa duis vitae non rhoncus nunc, orci sit maecenas ut, aliquet amet, vitae sit. Quam velit rutrum justo varius felis ligula, ut habitasse mauris, platea nunc. Et tincidunt vel, libero vitae aliquet donec suspendisse arcu, faucibus orci. Praesent mollis diam eu justo, quam diam arcu vel tincidunt. Aliquam eu fusce ipsum, ante turpis sociosqu, quis posuere pellentesque in pellentesque, nulla sit, phasellus lorem inceptos. Sociis ornare quam magnis eget cursus, ut pretium, velit vitae et sit vivamus, mi malesuada at lectus amet amet vitae. Convallis tristique gravida cras aenean, amet risus sem vehicula ac lacinia et, elit ac, magna eget ut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always found the the `sizer` element `proportion` is your friend in cases like these. Which defines how much room a certain element should take up in relation to others.
Here is your code, with the proportion option being used.

```
import wx
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Demonstrate wxPython button')
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
       # self.Fit()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        # Button
        button_sizer = self._button_sizer(frame)
        # Main sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(button_sizer,proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def _button_sizer(self, frame):
        cmd_save = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_SAVE)
        cmd_cancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button_sizer.Add(cmd_save)
        button_sizer.Add((-1, -1), proportion=1)
        button_sizer.Add(cmd_cancel)
        return button_sizer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks Rolf

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to add your buttons to the frame itself. The frame should only have one child, a panel. In this case, its only child should be an instance of your `MainPanel` class. You could just change your call to `_button_sizer` to the following:

```
button_sizer = self._button_sizer(self)
```

Note that here we are passing the `_button_sizer` the panel as its parent instead of the frame.

Of course, you can also move the creation of the buttons completely outside of the class if you want to:

```
import wx

def save_cancel(parent):
    cmd_save = wx.Button(parent, wx.ID_SAVE)
    cmd_cancel = wx.Button(parent, wx.ID_CANCEL)
    button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    button_sizer.Add(cmd_save)
    button_sizer.Add(cmd_cancel, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    return button_sizer

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,
                          'Demonstrate wxPython button')
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Fit()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)

        # Button
        button_sizer = save_cancel(self)

        # Main sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add((400, 0))
        main_sizer.Add(button_sizer)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Fit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

This will make binding events trickier, but it's one interesting way to make your code a bit more modular as well.

If you want the buttons to be separate, then you add a `StretchSpacer` or a tuple like `(-1, -1)` (see Rolf's answer). Here's an example using the `StretchSpacer`:

```
import wx



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1,
                          'Demonstrate wxPython button')
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Fit()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)

        # Button
        button_sizer = self.save_cancel()

        # Main sizer
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add((400, 0))
        main_sizer.Add(button_sizer, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def save_cancel(self):
        cmd_save = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_SAVE)
        cmd_cancel = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CANCEL)
        button_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        button_sizer.Add(cmd_save)
        button_sizer.AddStretchSpacer()
        button_sizer.Add(cmd_cancel, flag=wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        return button_sizer    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I thought my frame only had one child: MainPanel. Maybe, I've misunderstood, but all you seem to have done is move around the creation of the button sizer. Has this answered my question about the alignment of the buttons? I want the Cancel button to appear on the right hand side of the main frame, and the save button on the left hand side

Comment: You passed the frame object to your panel and then you set the frame as the parent of your buttons. Which is probably not what you want. If you want the buttons to be separate from each other, that's actually pretty easy. I added a separate example. Rolf also had a good way to do it too.

Comment: Thanks Mike. That's good too. Didn't know about "AddStretchSpacer"; very useful

Comment: "You passed the frame object to your panel and then you set the frame as the parent of your buttons. Which is probably not what you want". Not sure what I want :) the widgets on the panel will generally be displaying or reacting to items belonging to the frame (in a large app the panel might be a separate module), so would you consider it best practice to keep all widgets on the panel and adjust frame code accordingly?

Comment: As I mentioned, most of the time the only widget you want on your frame is the panel. The only other widgets you might have on a frame would be a toolbar, menu and statusbar. The panel will hold everything else, including other panels. So yes, I would highly recommend keeping the majority of your code in the panel or separate classes.